# pandas - draw two dataframe in one plot but xticks on top and bottom

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to draw 2 dataframe with different x label in one plot. but now the first draw x label will be override by second draw x label. how to move the second x label to the top?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
idx = 0
for i in range(1,50):
    df1.loc[idx,'name'] = 'A' + str(i)
    df1.loc[idx,'value'] = 40*i
    idx += 1
    
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
idx = 0
for i in range(1,50):
    df2.loc[idx,'name'] = 'B' + str(i)
    df2.loc[idx,'value'] = i*i
    idx += 1

df1.plot(x='name',y='value',ax=ax)
df2.plot(x='name',y='value',ax=ax)


#plt.savefig(pngname)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ax.twiny()` function to make a new axis:

```
ax2 = ax.twiny()
df1.plot(x='name',y='value',ax=ax)
df2.plot(x='name',y='value',ax=ax2, color = 'orange')
```

instead of:

```
df1.plot(x='name',y='value',ax=ax)
df2.plot(x='name',y='value',ax=ax)
```

Will give you:

[image]